# custom selectbox, slideup if not the custom selectbox and its children is click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the middle of creating a custom select box. What I want is when not the custom select box (the element that has a class of selectbox_ui) and its children is clicked then slideUp else if custom select box (the element that has a class of selectbox_ui) and its children is clicked then slideDown. Below is my code snippet yet the function that supposed to bring the select box options up and down is sadly not working. Any help, suggestion, recommendation, clues and ideas is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thehide").hide();
    $(".selectbox_ui").click(function (e) {
        var current_event = $(this);
        if ($(".selectbox_ui_dp", this).is(":visible")) {
            $(".selectbox_ui_dp", this).slideUp();
        } else {
            $(".selectbox_ui_dp", this).slideDown();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr("class") !== "selectbox_ui") {
            $(".selectbox_ui_dp").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.selectbox_ui {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin: 0px;
    font: normal 15px 'mplight', sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    background: none;
}

    .selectbox_ui .selectbox_ui_label {
        color: #5a5a5a;
        font: normal 15px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 93%;
    }

        .selectbox_ui .selectbox_ui_label span {
            display: block;
        }

.selectbox_ui_dp {
    width: 94%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0px;
    font: normal 15px 'mplight', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

    .selectbox_ui_dp li {
        text-decoration: none;
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        list-style: none;
    }

        .selectbox_ui_dp li a {
            font: normal 15px 'mplight', sans-serif;
            color: #5a5a5a;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

.dodong_ui .input_wrapper {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    display: block;
}

    .dodong_ui .input_wrapper label {
        color: #5a5a5a;
        font: normal 15px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .dodong_ui .input_wrapper select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        border-top: none;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
        margin: 0px;
        font: normal 15px 'mplight', sans-serif;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    }

    .dodong_ui .input_wrapper input, .dodong_ui .input_wrapper textarea {
        background: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        border-top: none;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
        margin: 0px;
        font: normal 15px 'mplight', sans-serif;
        height: 26px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .dodong_ui .input_wrapper input:focus, .dodong_ui .input_wrapper input:active, .dodong_ui .input_wrapper input:hover, .dodong_ui .input_wrapper textarea:active, .dodong_ui .input_wrapper textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

.dodong_ui button {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px 11px 3px 11px;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24;
    background: #76b729;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row daselect clear extend dodong_ui">
    <form class="ajaxform extend clear">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_sender" value="ebdul kerem muhemmed abubeker" />
        <fieldset>
            <div class="input_wrapper extend clear">
                <!-- <select class="extend clear" name="urgency" required="">
                                <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
                            </select> -->
                <div class="extend clear selectbox_ui">
                    <div class="selectbox_ui_label extend clear"><span class="extend align_left">Urgency Level</span><span class="ion-ios-arrow-down align_right"></span></div>
                    <ul class=" thehide selectbox_ui_dp extend clear">
                        <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Urgent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrapper extend clear">
                <label class="extend clear">attachment</label>
                <input class="extend clear" type="text" class="extend clear attachment" value="" required />
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrapper extend clear">
                <label class="extend clear">Message</label>
                <textarea class="extend clear" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrapper extend clear">
                <button class="extend clear">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that you need. You can use stopPropagation instead of preventdefault. Also use target to find the attr.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thehide").hide();
$(".selectbox_ui").click(function(e){
            var current_event = $(this);
            if($(".selectbox_ui_dp", this).is(":visible")){
                $(".selectbox_ui_dp", this).slideUp();
            }else{
                $(".selectbox_ui_dp", this).slideDown();
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).on("click", function(e){
            if(!($(e.target).hasClass("selectbox_ui"))){
               $(".selectbox_ui_dp").slideUp();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: perhaps you dont quite get it. What i want is when I click to other element  (anything on the document just not the selectbox_ui) the selecbox_ui should slideUp.